# Cannot get CASE working for a NULL substitution.

Tags: mysql, sql

My code sample below:

I want to look up contracts that have started, AND may or may not have an end date. If the end date is later than today, or not yet specified (NULL / empty), then great.

```
SELECT 
   ID, BeginDate, EndDate,
CASE
   WHEN EndDate IS NULL 
    THEN curdate()+1
END as FinishDate
FROM 
    contracts
WHERE 
    (id=1) AND
    (CURDATE() BETWEEN BeginDate and FinishDate);
```

But I'm getting

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'FinishDate' in 'where clause
```

What am I missing?

Comment: aliases dont work in where statements

Comment: Changed the sql-server tag to mysql based on comments (and the syntax of `CURDATE()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `FinishDate` is not a column of the original table, so the scope of its identifier is limited to the `ORDER BY` clause; it cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause.

There are several ways to work around this problem. The simplest one is to copy the expression into the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
   ID, BeginDate, EndDate,
CASE
   WHEN EndDate IS NULL 
    THEN curdate()+1
END as FinishDate
FROM 
    contracts
WHERE 
    (id=1) AND
    (CURDATE() BETWEEN (CASE WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN curdate()+1 END) and FinishDate);
```

Note: most RDBMSs have a special operator for providing null replacement expressions. In MS SQL Server that's `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT 
   ID, BeginDate, EndDate,
   ISNULL(EndDate, curdate()+1) as FinishDate
FROM 
    contracts
WHERE 
    (id=1) AND
    (CURDATE() BETWEEN ISNULL(EndDate, curdate()+1) and FinishDate);
```

Comment: Do I still need the first Case Statement? I'm not actually needing "FinishDate" - that was just a workaround. (This is MySQL btw)

Comment: @Maxcot In `MySQL` you can use `COALESCE(EndDate, curdate()+1)`. If you do not need the `FinishDate` in the output, you can remove it from the `select` list.

Comment: +1 . . . This is a really good explanation for SQL Server, which the question was originally tagged for.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight... learnt something new, and exactly what I was looking for. (COALESCE)

Comment: Another important point: The underlying table structure must allow the  end date field to be NULL. In using PHP I struggled for some time until I found that my field value wasn't NULL but 0000-00-00.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can actually move the condition to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT ID, BeginDate, EndDate,
       (CASE WHEN EndDate IS NULL 
             THEN curdate()+1
        END) as FinishDate
FROM contracts
WHERE (id=1)
HAVING (CURDATE() BETWEEN BeginDate and FinishDate);
```

This is a MySQL extension that allows you to use column aliases defined in `select` for filtering.  By the way, are you sure the logic is correct?  Do you really want it to be:

```
SELECT ID, BeginDate, EndDate, COALESCE(EndDate, curdate() + 1) as FinishDate
```

The difference is that your version puts `NULL` in for `FinishDate` when `EndDate` has a value.  This version uses `EndDate` if available and substitutes "tomorrow" if it is not available.